# SIGSTOP anything I haven't interacted with in 10 minutes?

Tags: process, signals, gui, process-management

For working on multiple projects, I may open several applications in separate workspaces.

It's possible that while I'm working on one thing, the other set of applications are open but not in use. I wouldn't like to close them (e.g. I wouldn't like to close an IDE where I have some state like I'm on a certain line number or if I have some panes open), but I can often pause them via SIGSTOP and resume them via SIGCONT later.

This has the benefit that it pauses all of the application's background CPU activity while still keeping it in memory / swap.

Could I automate this? say (from a whitelist) if I haven't interacted with a GUI application in last N minutes, send it a SIGSTOP signal, and if I try to focus its GUI then send it a SIGCONT signal?

I can write the script myself, but I don't know:

1. How do I observe / monitor events about some interaction (mouse click, typing) with some application?
2. How do I observe the information that I tried to click on a SIGSTOP'D frozen GUI application?

Comment: You seem to have a badly behaved IDE. What background tasks is it running? do you need them? what events are they reacting to? can you stop them?

Comment: That was just one example. Even if I trust an application to behave well, there is no guarantee. Pausing them, however, I get a guarantee from the OS. So I'd like to use that option rather than chasing down details of how applications may be misbehaving.